# SDK 4.6 - Waypoint Mission, Follow Me Mission and HotPoint Mission support for Spark

Tags: dji-sdk

in release note of the android DJI SDK 4.6 i can see support for mission for the spark, but in the release note for iOS for the same SDK version it's not mentioned..
so really mission will not work on iOS with the spark? or is only a missing in the release note?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are supported in 4.6.1 - For example see last comment in this thread
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/issues/192 for iOS - it's working!

Comment: thanks, good to know! so it probably already worked from 4.6 but they forgot to mention it in the release notes.